# How to scrape real time streaming data with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape the number of flights for this webpage https://www.flightradar24.com/56.16,-49.51

The number is highlighted in the picture below:
[image]

The number is updated every 8 seconds.

This is what I tried with BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

r=requests.get("https://www.flightradar24.com/56.16,-49.51")
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
value=soup.find_all("span",{"class":"choiceValue"})
print(value)
```

But that always returns 0:

```
[<span class="choiceValue" id="menuPlanesValue">0</span>]
```

View source also shows 0, so I understand why BeautifulSoup returns 0 too.

Anyone know any other method to get the current value?

Comment: I think the values are updated through javascript, and after the page is loaded, the initial value is 0. So you need somehow to execute the js before scraping the content. Otherwise, you will always get zero.

Comment: @linusg Any lead on how to do that?

Comment: I was right, see the answer of @Andre!

Comment: If you're interrested I can write some basic code to retrieve the json and process it... May take some minutes, but if it helps you... :)

Comment: @linusg thanks. I am trying `c=r.json()["list"]` but getting a `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Comment: See my answer and feel free to comment on it!

Comment: You're getting the error, because the site gives an 403 error page without a correct user-agent in the header, so you get HTML instead of JSON.

Comment: Have you seen my answer??

Comment: @linusg looking at it now. Thanks a lot. Passing headers fixed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the page first loads a view, then performs regular requests to refresh the page. If you look at the network tab in the developer console in Chrome (for example), you'll see the requests to https://data-live.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?bounds=59.09,52.64,-58.77,-47.71&faa=1&mlat=1&flarm=1&adsb=1&gnd=1&air=1&vehicles=1&estimated=1&maxage=7200&gliders=1&stats=1

The response is regular json:

```
{
  "full_count": 11879,
  "version": 4,
  "afefdca": [
    "A86AB5",
    56.4288,
    -56.0721,
    233,
    38000,
    420,
    "0000",
    "T-F5M",
    "B763",
    "N641UA",
    1473852497,
    "LHR",
    "ORD",
    "UA929",
    0,
    0,
    "UAL929",
    0
  ],
  ...
  "aff19d9": [
    "A12F78",
    56.3235,
    -49.3597,
    251,
    36000,
    436,
    "0000",
    "F-EST",
    "B752",
    "N176AA",
    1473852497,
    "DUB",
    "JFK",
    "AA291",
    0,
    0,
    "AAL291",
    0
  ],
  "stats": {
    "total": {
      "ads-b": 8521,
      "mlat": 2045,
      "faa": 598,
      "flarm": 152,
      "estimated": 464
    },
    "visible": {
      "ads-b": 0,
      "mlat": 0,
      "faa": 6,
      "flarm": 0,
      "estimated": 3
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this API is protected in any way, but it seems like I can access it without any issues using curl.

More info:

- [aviation.stackexchange - Is there an API to get real-time FAA flight data?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/is-there-an-api-to-get-real-time-faa-flight-data)
- [Flightradar24 Forum - API access](http://forum.flightradar24.com/threads/24-API-access/page3) (meaning your use case is probably discouraged)

Comment: By the way is there any standard way to find the correct JSON request among all the requests in the Network tab?

Answer (score 7):

So based on what @Andre has found out, I wrote this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def get_count():
    url = "https://data-live.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?bounds=59.09,52.64,-58.77,-47.71&faa=1&mlat=1&flarm=1&adsb=1&gnd=1&air=1&vehicles=1&estimated=1&maxage=7200&gliders=1&stats=1"

    # Request with fake header, otherwise you will get an 403 HTTP error
    r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

    # Parse the JSON
    data = r.json()
    counter = 0

    # Iterate over the elements to get the number of total flights
    for element in data["stats"]["total"]:
        counter += data["stats"]["total"][element]

    return counter

while True:
    print(get_count())
    time.sleep(8)
```

The code should be self explaining, everything it does is printing the actual flight count every 8 seconds :)

**Note:** *The values are similar to the ones on the website, but not the same. This is because it's unlikely, that the Python script and the website are sending a request at the same time. If you want to get more accurate results, just make a request every 4 seconds for example.*

Use this code as you want, extend it or whatever. Hope this helps!

Comment: Why on earth would you use `eval` over calling  `r.json()`? Or at the very least calling `json.loads(r.content)` which is what`r.json()` would be doing.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - Hmm, that was just my first thaught. As I wrote, the code is not meant as something final :D

Comment: @linusg: very interesting! indeed as you mention sometimes the values in the Python script are different than the website. What is Python doing in these cases, is it computing an interpolated value?

Comment: Uh, that was some time ago. As far as I can remember (!=AFAIR), the data is live, so it will differ each time you make a request. As I wrote, the Python Script and the Browser will not make requests at the *exact* same time, this is because the values will be different to some degree. Just make a request more often to get similar results as in the browser. It shouldn't matter, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org) to crawl a webpage with dynamic content added by javascript.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get('https://www.flightradar24.com/56.16,-49.51/3')

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
result = soup.find_all("span", {"id": "menuPlanesValue"})

for item in result:
    print(item.text)

browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Note: This is an old question. My answer is for future readers.`

If the accepted answer from Andres is still correct, then the data is not really streamed but rather fetched from the api.
I have posted an example of how to scrape data from a live website using Selenium and a WebSocket server.

The steps are:

1. Open the website with Selenium (or similar software).
2. Run a [WebSocket server](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to collect and process the data.
3. Inject JavaScript to the website that:

   i) Connects to the WebSocket server.

   ii) Observes the data changes (using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?retiredLocale=de)) and sends them to the WebSocket.
4. Process the data in your application, such as aggregating and storing it.

You can find the minimal example here: https://github.com/rbnbr/LiveWebsiteScraper/blob/main/minimal_example.py

This method avoids many GET requests by reusing the existing connections unless the website does them itself.

Comment: Is this possible to link to a cell in Excel?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with excel but you might be able to store the data in some file and use an excel external data source to include this file into excel, and thus, link to a cell.

Comment: I'm working on a way to run the script on my webserver as a python script and then use Excel's data access features to read the output from the resulting JSON file.  I'll hopefully update this as I get it working...