# Need help on figuring out how to scrape real time streaming data with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape the Current Usage for this local web server. This number updates every second with values that are generated from a random number generator.

> Current Time: 07:25:16 UTC
>
> Current Date: 2018-11-28 UTC
>
> Current Usage: 13 kW

This is what I've tried with Beautifulsoup so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeatifulSoup
import time

def get_count():
  url = "http://10.0.0.206/apps/cy8ckit_062_demo/main.html"

  # request with fake header, otherwise you will get an 403 HTTP error
  r = request.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': Mozilla/5.0})

while True:
  print(get_count())
  time.sleep(8)
```

However, when I run this script, I get an output 'None' every 8 seconds

Here is the output of the inspection of the web server:

> Current Time: 07:39:42 UTC
>
> Current Date 2018-11-28 UTC
>
> Current Usage: 8 kW

I've been trying to follow this: [How to scrape real time streaming data with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489168/how-to-scrape-real-time-streaming-data-with-python/39489328)

This is what I get as an output after trying @chitown88 code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/seniord/csusite/readweb.py", line 14, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
NameError: name 'r' is not defined
```

After trying the revised code from @chitown88, I get this as an output(Doesn't show the dynamic values but I thought beautifulsoup fixes that issue):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link href="../../styles/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<title>CE222494 PSoC 6 WICED WiFi Demo</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<script src="../../scripts/general_ajax_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
       function reloadData()
       {
         do_ajax('/temp_report.html', ajax_handler);
         timeoutID = setTimeout('reloadData()', 500);
       }
      function ajax_handler( result, data )
      {
        switch( result )
        {
            case AJAX_PARTIAL_PROGRESS:
                break;
            case AJAX_STARTING:
                break;
            case AJAX_FINISHED:
                document.getElementById("currentData").innerHTML = data;
                break;
            case AJAX_NO_BROWSER_SUPPORT:
                document.getElementById("currentData").innerHTML = "Failed - your browser does not support this script";
                break;
            case AJAX_FAILED:
                document.getElementById("currentData").innerHTML = "There was a problem retrieving data";
                break;
        }
      }

    /* ]]> */
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="reloadData()">
<div id="currentData">Retrieving current usage data...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Paste the code into the question via [edit], highlight the code and press Ctrl + K to enter between code tags.

Comment: Polling data at intervals is not exactly "real time"

Comment: Your function get_count doesn’t return anything. And you actually haven’t ysed BeautifulSoup for anything. Once you have r, you need to use BeautifulSoup to pull out the data you’re wanting to print. So store that as some variable ‘data = (the info you pull from r)’ then you’ll need to ‘return data’

Comment: and as the others stated, please post the code rather than a picture of it.

Comment: What output are you wanting? are you looking for it to just print out the text Current Time: 07:25:16 UTC

Current Date: 2018-11-28 UTC

Current Usage: 13 kW?

Comment: @chitown88 I want to scrape the (dynamic) values of Current Time and Current usage. However, these values are constantly changing on the web server every few seconds with a random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

your code is incomplete. Specifically, 1) you actually haven't used BeautifulSoup to do anything, and 2) your function doesn't return anything which is why it prints 'None'

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4 
from requests_html import HTMLSession 
import time

def get_count():

    url = 'http://10.0.0.206/apps/cy8ckit_062_demo/main.html'

    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=5,timeout=8)

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')

    data = soup.findAll('div', {'id':'currentData'})[0]
    temp_data = data.findAll('p')
    current_time = temp_data[0].text
    current_date = temp_data[1].text
    current_usage = temp_data[2].text

    print ('%s\n%s\n%s' %(current_time, current_date, current_usage))



while True:
    get_count()
    time.sleep(8)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to python, so some step by step guidance would GREATLY be appreciated! I want to scrape the (dynamic) values of Current Time and Current usage. These values are constantly changing on the web server every few seconds with a random number generator. Basically I want to continuously scrape these values every time it changes just like it does in the flight radar example that I referred to. I tried following this example and just replaced my URL with their URL, but I get a error (probably because mine is not  JSON)?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the place for that, but I'll try to help you out. refer to my post/answer, I'll edit, and then if you can edit your post/question as follow ups, might be able to make this work

Comment: Thank you so much for understanding!!! I've been trying to solve this problem for weeks! I have posted the error I get when trying to run what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

`main.html` is wrong URL, its for displaying data from `temp_report.html` (ajax)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeatifulSoup
import time

def get_count():
    url = "http://10.0.0.206/temp_report.html
    # or
    # url = "http://10.0.0.206/apps/cy8ckit_062_demo/temp_report.html

    # request with fake header, otherwise you will get an 403 HTTP error
    r = request.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': Mozilla/5.0})
    page_source = r.text
    # print(page_source)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)

    # html_body = soup.find('body') # <body>this_text</body>
    # print(html_body.text) # this_text

    # paragraphs = soup.find_all('p') # <body> <p>p1</p> <p>p2</p> </body>
    # for p in paragraphs:
    #    print(p.text) # p1, p2


while True:
    print(get_count())
    time.sleep(8)
```